# Update table using values from the same table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to update rows of a table that contain an "NA" value for a column. Instead of the "NA" value, this cell should contain a file number which is found in another cell in the same row. The data look like this --

| File_num | File_number |
| --- | --- |
| NA | 182678 |
| NA | 183679 |

I am confused if I need to use a join or not, and I can't figure out how a subquery would work here. I initially wrote the following which would join on the unique ID, an accession number--

```sql
UPDATE t
SET t.file_num = z.file_number
from table t
INNER JOIN table z ON t.accession = z.accession
WHERE t.file_num = "NA"
```

But it seems like the join may be unnecessary and maybe create some other problems? Since I am updating with data found in the same table and same row, could it just be--

```sql
UPDATE t
SET t.file_num = t.file_number
from table t
WHERE t.file_num = "NA"
```

Comment: Did you try executing second query?

Comment: Yes, I did, and it actually worked because I was lucky enough to have 1:1 relationship between these two variables for each row. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [sql fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4k6QNSusEdXUDgtwrxViwZ/1)

```
UPDATE your_table_name
SET file_num = file_number
WHERE file_num = 'NA';
```

If you're updating values within the same row and the condition is based on the value of a column in that row, you generally don't need a join. Your second query looks close to what you need, but I guess the better syntax would be to use the column name in the assignment statement rather than the table alias.

Comment: Indeed, that worked. I didn't need the join. Thanks for responding!

Comment: You are welcome. You can write up an answer if my wasn't satisfactory or check my if it was because people don't tend to read comments, they like to see green check sign.

Comment: Done, sorry for taking so long to do it.